# ListView, ListViewItem, and how to access SubItems

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a VB ListView (called 'lvRecords') with 13 columns in it. I am then adding Items to the ListView, with each Item being defined as below:-

```
    Dim item As ListViewItem

    Dim columns(13) As String

    columns(0) = "some string"
    columns(1) = "another string"
    ...       ...         .......
    columns(13) = "final string"

    item = New ListViewItem(columns)
    lvRecords.Items.Add(item)
```

I am then wishing to 'access' one of the array elements of any particular item. How do I do this? I have tried item.SubItems(0).ToString, thinking that this will access the 'column(0)' of one of the items, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The subitems are a collection in the ListViewItem.  `myLV.Items(0).SubItems(0).Text` will be the text for the first item (row) in the first column.  `myLV.Items(0).SubItems(1).Text` will be first row, second column.  With that many columns a DataGridView would likely be easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I'm sure I tried this & it didnt work, does now though

Answer (score 0):

Try to used this.

```
 MessageBox.Show(lvRecords.Items(x).SubItems(y).Text)
```

Note : Where **x** is the row number and **y** is the column noumber.

For example :
Based on your example code.

```
MessageBox.Show(lvRecords.Items(0).SubItems(1).Text)
```

Output will be : another string